# How can I debug code that's running in a container without attaching VSCode to the container?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, debugging, vscode-remote

I want to debug code that is running in containers on my local machine.
For instance, I want to debug the service `airflow-worker` which is part of my Docker Compose along other services.

I don't want to attach to the container because my codebase isn't mirrored one to one to the container and I like seeing it like it is on my local machine rather than what's mounted to the container.

How can I [debug code that's running in a container](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/containers/debug-common) *without* attaching to the container in the [Dev Containers](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-remote-release) extension?